# tabs not showing

Tags: forms, routes

I know this question have been answered many times but i realy do not know what i'm doing wrong. I want a config page of my module with 2 tabs in it. But it won't show a thing.
here is the hook_menu();

```
function drupangelsToolbar_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/config/drupangelsToolbar'] = array(
        'title' => 'drupangels toolbar module settings',
        'description' => 'configuration of your drupangels toolbar',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('drupangelsToolbar_admin'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer drupangelsToolbar settings'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
          );
    $items['admin/config/drupangelsToolbar/add'] = array(
        'title' => 'add',
        'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
        'weight' => 0
         );
    $items['admin/config/drupangelsToolbar/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'delete',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('drupangelsToolbarTab3_admin'),
        'weight' => 2
        );
    return $items;
}
```

this is the hook_admin()

```
function drupangelsToolbar_admin() {
    drupangelsToolbarTab1_admin();
    drupangelsToolbarTab3_admin();  
}
```

in drupangelsToolbarTab1_admin() and drupangelsToolbarTab3_admin() I built the forms, ending with  return system_settings_form($form);

What am I dong wrong ??
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong:

add needs a callback. E.g:

```
$items['admin/config/drupangelsToolbar/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'add',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 0,
    'page callback' => 'my_callback_function',
);
```

Otherwise it has no action when it is clicked.

add and delete both need either an "access callback" or "access arguments". E.g:

```
$items['admin/config/drupangelsToolbar/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'add',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 0,
    'page callback' => 'my_callback_function',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items['admin/config/drupangelsToolbar/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'delete',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('drupangelsToolbarTab3_admin'),
    'weight' => 2,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```

Without this Drupal does not know whether or not to grant access to your tab so that is why they are not appearing.

Comment: but FYI, I only need to aply this to the delete tab because the add tap inherits this from the root item. Correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Comment: Ar ha - yes I believe your right there...